# check cpanel authorisation with perl script and write file

Tags: perl, cpanel

i was working on a perl script that check multi cpanel accounts authorisation for weak passwords , like that a server owner can check if his users are using a weak password and when connected to one write a file in the /public_html/ dir to informe the user .
i was thinking of using `cPanel::PublicAPI` :

```
my $cp = cPanel::PublicAPI->new(
       'user' => $username,
       'pass' => $password,
       'host' => $host,
     );
```

but i didn't know how to check if connected and how to write file in it ( [i've looked here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/cPanel-PublicAPI/lib/cPanel/PublicAPI.pod))

i found a script that check for authorisation :

```
$authx = encode_base64($user.":".$passwd);
my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto => "tcp",PeerAddr => "$host", PeerPort => "$port") || print " [-] Can not connect to the host";
print $sock "GET / HTTP/1.1";
print $sock "Authorization: Basic $authx";
print $sock "Connection: Close";
read $sock, $answer, 128;
close($sock);

if ($answer =~ /Moved/) {
print " passord is : $passwd\n";
}
```

but this is too slow and can't write file using it .
sorry for my english :) . regards

Comment: That authorisation script is needlessly low-level. We have working HTTP libraries such as [LWP::UserAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent) for tasks like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i didn't know how to check if connected

Just make a request/method call on the `$cp` object. If it fails, the [`$cp->{error}` attribute](https://metacpan.org/module/MATTDEES/cPanel-PublicAPI-1.002/lib/cPanel/PublicAPI.pod#pubapi--error) is set.

> how to write file

```
use autodie qw(:all);
open my $fh, '>', '/home/user/message_from_the_admin';
$fh->print('You made a boo-boo.');
```

See chapter 9.3: *Files* in [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/).

Comment: thanks for help :)
but how can i call the $cp to check if it fails ?